# Change Div Size dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

In my code, I've got 4 divs aligned inline.

What I want is, on clicking any div, it resizes to fill the space of all 4 divs (width:1000px)
 and hides the other divs.

And on reclicking the div, it'll resize to the original dimensions.

This is what i've done till now.

`<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc2" onclick="document.getElementById('bloc2').style.width = '980px'">
</div>`

As of now, on click this resizes the div below the other divs. I know there's a method to hide the other divs, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ouch...I'd be tempted to use a framework like jQuery to help your brain be less hurt doing something like this...

Comment: The CSS for the div is `.gallery-image-replenish{
 background: url('../images/thumbs/Replenish.jpg');
 height:600px;
 width:246px;
 float: left;
 margin-left:3px;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 text-align: center;`
and the div markup is as mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use jQuery (jquery.com) on your project?

Because it would save a lot of code (and make it more readable!).
It would look like this (not tested, but probably works :P):

```
<div id="bloc1" class="gallery-image-replenish">1</div>
<div id="bloc2" class="gallery-image-replenish">2</div>
<div id="bloc3" class="gallery-image-replenish">3</div>
<div id="bloc4" class="gallery-image-replenish">4</div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var galleryElements = $('.gallery-image-replenish');
      galleryElements.click(function(){
        var clickedElement = $(this);
        if (clickedElement.hasClass('expanded')) { // if it has the class expanded, remove it (and show other elements again)
          clickedElement.removeClass('expanded');
          galleryElements.show();
        } else { // if it has not got the expanded css class hide other and add class to expanded
          galleryElements.not(clickedElement).hide(); // hide every other div
          $(this).addClass('expanded'); // add stylesheet class for the new bigger width
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

With this kind of HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc1"></div>
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc2"></div>
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc3"></div>
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc4"></div>
```

you can use this kind of JS:

```
var handler = function(e){
    e.target.style.width = "1000px";
    for (j = divs.length; j--; ) {
        if (divs[j].id != e.target.id) {
            divs[j].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-image-replenish'); //array of divs
var div;

for (i = divs.length; i--; ) {
    div = divs[i];
    div.addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution for a pure Javascript-based way of doing things...is there an error in your `for` loop by the way?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. `i--` returns decreasing number, which starts from length of array. When `i` reaches zero, boolean value of this becomes false.

Comment: Wow, interesting! I learnt something! Thanks for the feedback @Oshibka404 :)

Answer (score 0):

The pure javascript way to hide an element is:

```
document.getElementById('otherdiv1').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution which uses a common javascript function to perform what you want:-

```
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc1" onclick="manageDivs(this.id)"> </div>
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc2" onclick="manageDivs(this.id)"> </div>
<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc3" onclick="manageDivs(this.id)"> </div>

<div class="gallery-image-replenish" id="bloc4" onclick="manageDivs(this.id)"> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function manageDivs(divId)
    {
    document.getElementById(divId).style.width = '980px'";
    //to hide rest of the divs
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        if(divId!='bloc'+i)
           document.getElementById('bloc'+i).style.display = 'none';

    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works in resizing the divs. What about on second click, it resizing back to original? That's where i encounter my main obstacle. It's the resizing to original.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/YpqCg/) is a simple exemple ,

```
var activ = false;
$('.aligned').live('click',function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('actif')) {

        $('.aligned').css('width','0');
        $('.aligned').removeClass('actif');

        $(this).css('width','1000px');
        $(this).addClass('actif');

    } else {
        $('.aligned').css('width','250px');
    }

});
```

you can use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more visual effect